# Please help understanding Haskell Parallel

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I have read some docs, using fibonacci as example. Then I started trying to parallelise my code mostly working with list. My code did not get any faster.

Sample code:

```hs
parMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
parMap f = withStrategy (parList rseq) . map f

parZipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
parZipWith f as = withStrategy (parList rseq) . zipWith f as

main = do
  let rips = parMap parseIPRange [] -- huge list of items like "192.168.3.1/24"
      result = parZipWith checkSubnets rips (tail rips ++ [IPRange 0 0])
  print result
```

I think I must have misunderstood the whole thing.

PS: The whole thing is a migrating of https://github.com/magicloud/ip_helper, which is Rust with Rayon.

Comment: Have you tried `rDeepSeq` instead of `rSeq`? Isn't your sorting definition just a baseless recursion?

Comment: Oh, why am I so stupid.... Let me fix the sort first.

Comment: was all it took changing to `rDeepSeq`? Perhaps you can post the complete and working code as an answer, just for posterity's sake :)

Answer (score 3):

Following @ATayler 's suggestion, I did following changes.

1. Enable `DeriveGeneric`
2. Import `GHC.Generics`
3. Derive `Generic` for all my types.
4. Make functions I need:

```
parMap :: (NFData b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
parMap f = withStrategy (parList rdeepseq). map f
parFilter :: (NFData a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
parFilter f = withStrategy (parList rdeepseq) . filter f
parZipWith :: (NFData c) => (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
parZipWith f as = withStrategy (parList rdeepseq). zipWith f as
parSortBy :: (NFData a) => (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
parSortBy f = withStrategy (parList rdeepseq) . sortBy f
```

5. Call them when appropriate.

Now the time cut to 1/3 of the original single threaded one, with full CPU used. Not sure if there can be other major optimizing.